# Getting text from PDF using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, txt

How can I get infromation about the structure of pdf, I mean text or pic? I need my programm to move pdf without text in other folder, but now I'm getting just an empty txt file.

```java
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile)) {
                PDDocument document = new PDDocument().load(file);
                PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String text = pdfTextStripper.getText(document);
                writer.write(text);
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Also, have a problem with getting text from saved in pdf web-pages. It looks like:

[image: example of txt]

I think there is something wrong with encoding, but don't know what to do

Comment: *"the structure of pdf, I mean text or pic"* - what exactly do you mean? Merely something like the ratio of text to images? Which kind of images, vector graphics or bitmaps?... *"I think there is something wrong with encoding, but don't know what to do"* - usually something like that means that the pdf does not contain the data required for text extraction. Have you tested whether copy&paste from Adobe Reader returns something better?

Comment: "the structure of pdf, I mean text or pic"  - I mean, that pdf can contain only pictures without text, for example scanned document saved in pdf. 
"Have you tested whether copy&paste from Adobe Reader returns something better?" - tested in default ubuntu document viewer, it's ok

Comment: If as a result of text extraction as above you get (nearly) nothing, you can look for images. See the `PrintImageLocations` PDFBox example as an example for proper image information retrieval. ... *"tested in default ubuntu document viewer, it's ok"* - in that case we'd need an example PDF to inspect.

Comment: @mkl Thanks a lot, here is my pdf https://dropmefiles.com/qr8VQ. It's saved news web-page from CNN

Comment: I just tested text extraction from your example PDF and it worked alright. Which PDFBox version do you use?

Comment: Please replace `new PDDocument().load()` with `PDDocument.load()`, this is a static method. (It's not related to your problem, but it is bad code which will bring a warning about document not getting closed)

Comment: @mkl I use version 2.0.21

Comment: @TilmanHausherr ty, will change, just learning

Comment: I just switched from the development head to 2.0.21 but still have no problems extracting text from your example PDF. Ah, I just could reproduce an image like yours: The output text is UTF-8 encoded, but by forcing my text viewer to assume UTF-16 encoding, the output looks the same as yours. Thus, either switch your text viewer to UTF-8 or explicitly tell your `FileWriter` to use UTF-16.

Comment: @mkl, thanks a lot, just tried to open document with LibreOffice Writer and it's ok, I think it's because of specific fonts. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works alright, your text viewer assumes a wrong encoding.

Using your code and the same PDFBox version as you I get proper extracted text:

[image: viewer screen shot, UTF-8 encoding assumed]

But when I force my viewer to assume UTF-16 encoding, I get something very similar to what you get:

[image: viewer screen shot, UTF-16 encoding assumed]

The file itself does not indicate any specific encoding by a BOM or anything:

[image: viewer screen shot, hex dump view]

Thus, your text viewer either incorrectly *guesses* UTF-16 encoding or is *configured* to use it.

Thus, either switch your text viewer to use UTF-8 or explicitly tell your `FileWriter` to use UTF-16.

---

Depending on your specific installation, the file encoding might actually be different. As my UTF-16 view looks so very much like yours, though, the encoding very likely is at least similar to UTF-8, probably some ISO 8859-x...